# uniq treats lines as equal when they are not

Tags: uniq

I would expect different output from this command:

```
$ echo -e "あいうえお\nオエウイア" | uniq -c
      2 あいうえお
```

The two lines are **not** the same.
Compare to this example, working as expected:

```
$ echo -e "aiueo\noeuia" | uniq -c
      1 aiueo
      1 oeuia
```

Is this a Unicode or UTF-8 issue? I did not find any option to support "exotic" characters.

Edit: I am experiencing a similar problem when using sort with japanese input. Input of the form `a\nb\na\nb\n` (or, ommiting '\n', `abab`) stays that way, I would expect it to be `aabb` or at least `bbaa`.

Comment: In my environment, it works as expected. Which version of `uniq` and `sort` are you using ? mine is `uniq (GNU coreutils) 8.26` on Arch Linux

Comment: mine are GNU coreutils 8.23, Ubuntu.

Comment: I confirmed that in some locale, the `uniq` behaves like your question. However, I could not reproduce the `sort` issue. check your `LANG`, `LC_ALL`, or output of `locale` command, and try something like `echo -e "あいうえお\nオエウイア" | LC_COLLATE=C uniq -c`  or `echo -e "a\nb\na\nb\n" | LC_ALL=C sort`

Comment: Setting LC_COLLATE seems to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go - `echo -e "あいうえお\nオエウイア" | uni2ascii -q  | uniq -c | ascii2uni`

Comment: Works, thank you! Interesting, do you have any explanation as to why plain uniq/sort have this strange behavior? I mean, what use is a sorting order which says a < b < a?

Comment: Who knows? Probably some default behavior  in uniq source code and how it treats non-ascii chars or chars beyond a specific unicode range. Maybe it's a Locale issue. Please accept my answer as it helped you :)